# Programatically build and launch contained applications based on Maven dependecies

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aether

I would like to take several lists of Maven dependencies from the user, resolve and load each of them as contained applications. Here are the steps:

1. collect a list of all Maven dependencies (DONE)
2. resolve all dependencies with Aether (DONE)
3. resolve classpath with Aether (DONE)
4. bundle the above in a separate "container" (so that different Maven dependencies with potential conflicting version can be used).
5. repeat with other lists.

To give some context: I want to use the above in the context of UIMA, to be able to run different (natural language processing) pipelines that rely on different sets of libraries with different versions. My goal is to create an annotation-server in which one defines (Maven) dependencies and pipelines that can be called in a RESTful way. The pipelines (and their corresponding dependencies) should each run in a contained classpath environment (so as to avoid classpath clashes).

Is OSGi the way to go? Based on a classpath (:= a list of resolved jar), can I then build an OSGi bundle and deploy it? All programmatically? I do not have control over the maven dependencies (they are UIMA components, that's it), so no way to add OSGi metadata there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would maven-assembly-plugin combined with maven profiles take care of this for you?

You can filter dependencies differently on a per profile basis. You can use profile specific assembly descriptor documents and generate custom manifest to be placed in the war. You are describing a J2EE Web Application (war) assembly -- they will run in a firewalled classloader inside a servlet container so you generate a bunch of them based on the same source (just vary the web app context and the contents of the WEB-INF/lib on a per profile basis.

Drop them into the same Tomcat server, for example, and you are ready to go. Was this what you meant?

HTH,

Nick

Comment: Thanks @nrapopor, sounds like a good idea. Could you elaborate on the "firewalled" classloaders inside a servlet container: I know UIMA uses some Class.forName() calls -- will it work? Well, I guess I will just try and see. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create a bundle that contains a list of jars, put all of those on the bundle's own classpath and deploy that bundle into an OSGi container. You probably do need to create a BundleActivator (which is the entry point for that bundle, like the main method is for traditional Java).

You then say you have multiple of such bundles, and do I understand correctly that you want to deploy each bundle in a separate container? If so, you can either use some kind of REST library to provide a REST endpoint for each bundle, or you can use OSGi remote services to publish a service that can be discovered by other containers.

I am not sure if this is what you mean, so I am also not sure if OSGi is the right way to go. From your description you use neither services (a very important reason to use OSGi as that decouples parts of your application from each other) nor do you intend to create different bundles for the components (another important reason to use OSGi). You are almost describing an architectural style currently hyped as "micro services". Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Thanks Marcel. The bundle would only expose a few REST endpoints, no other services.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a lot like you could use [Apache Stanbol](https://stanbol.apache.org/). It's a framework focused on semantic enhancement of content but can be used for any web based work flows involving content. You can define pipelines to process and/or store your data. There are components for NLP using Apache Tika and OpenNLP. As far as I know you can also integrate UIMA. It uses RESTful services and is based on OSGI.

---

If Stanbol doesn't fit your use case and you need to roll your own application, I think OSGI is still the way to go.

Depending on your use case you can either deploy bundles to a container or simply embed the OSGI framework in a small launcher app that loads the bundles you create.

Many Maven artifacts already contain OSGI metadata. Most of the time you can copy them to your bundle directory using the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and load them directly as OSGI bundles.

Non-OSGI dependencies can be embed in your the bundles that need them. It should also be possible to setup a few maven plugins to modify the manifest to add some meta data based on the maven artifact ids and version and repack the dependencies as bundles (this won't work all the time though, since the Maven pom version and the packages' versions aren't always the same).

The users code and any required dependencies can be bundled up using the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). It can generate the manifest for you.

For REST interfaces I usually would recommend JAX-RS (Jersey or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) DOSGI) but I haven't used the programmatic approach with those frameworks yet.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case I'd suggest you look into the [Java ServiceLoader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). The ServiceLoader API allows you to define an interface, and load implementations of that interface from different self-contained JARs. You can build your different libraries into their own jars, exposing the methods you need via the interface, and load them from your Java program independently. The ServiceLoader will even list the different implementations available for you.

From the documentation:
Suppose we have a service type com.example.CodecSet which is intended to represent sets of encoder/decoder pairs for some protocol. In this case it is an abstract class with two abstract methods:

```
public abstract Encoder getEncoder(String encodingName);
public abstract Decoder getDecoder(String encodingName);
```

Each method returns an appropriate object or null if the provider does not support the given encoding. Typical providers support more than one encoding.
If com.example.impl.StandardCodecs is an implementation of the CodecSet service then its jar file also contains a file named

```
META-INF/services/com.example.CodecSet
```

This file contains the single line:

```
com.example.impl.StandardCodecs        # Standard codecs
```

The CodecSet class creates and saves a single service instance at initialization:

```
private static ServiceLoader<CodecSet> codecSetLoader
        = ServiceLoader.load(CodecSet.class);
```

To locate an encoder for a given encoding name it defines a static factory method which iterates through the known and available providers, returning only when it has located a suitable encoder or has run out of providers.

```
public static Encoder getEncoder(String encodingName) {
        for (CodecSet cp : codecSetLoader) {
                Encoder enc = cp.getEncoder(encodingName);
                if (enc != null)
                        return enc;
        }
        return null;
}
```

A getDecoder method is defined similarly.